# python asyncio function add_done_callback is not working

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using Set() to do rate limiting feature in my program.
But there are some weird behaviours.

1. there are some residue in `task_set` which are not suppose to happen. I have added `add_done_callback` that the task will remove itself from `task_set` after it's done.
2. KeyError are sometimes thrown. But I have no ideas why, the task in `task_set` should not be removed more than 1 time

I have tried different approach (semaphore, queue...) but none of them worked as expected... I will be appreciated if anyone can share some code snippet on how to implement rate limiting in async programming

```
import asyncio


def main():
    async def task(acc_id):
        print(f"acc_id {acc_id} received the task")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(f"acc_id {acc_id} finished the task")

    async def loop_tasks():
        task_set = set()

        for acc_id in range(1000000):
            # pause when reached the limit
            while len(task_set) > 10:
                await asyncio.sleep(0)

            t = event_loop.create_task(task(acc_id))
            task_set.add(t)
            t.add_done_callback(lambda _: task_set.remove(t))

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(loop_tasks())


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the program output exception and found that `t` was the same value.

A review of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback) shows that when `callback` is called, the Future object is its only argument.

After making the following changes, the program runs normally.

```py
t.add_done_callback(lambda current_task: task_set.remove(current_task))
```